# Display an image on a button with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I create a music play/pause button with HTML, CSS and Javascript and would like the icon to change when the music is played or paused. Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gp7yf1t3/5/

HTML:

```
<audio id="player">
  <source src='https://audio.jukehost.co.uk/c926ef6560961d5fd02e35e1488a5997e8217bc1/1a1c12c319a' type='audio/mpeg'/>
</audio>

<button id="button"></button>
```

CSS:

```
#button {
 background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/laKFwvv.png);
 width: 64px;
 height: 64px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 border: 0;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25)
}

#button:active { background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.25); }

body { background: red; }
```

The current icon is a pause icon, but it's supposed to be a play icon. I also added "pause" when it's pause but I want to make it an icon instead.

Javascript:

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var audio = document.getElementById("player");

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(audio.paused){
    audio.play();
    button.innerHTML = "test";
  } else {
    audio.pause();
    button.innerHTML = "test";
  }
});
```

I tried it with symbol characters but it didn't look really nice and would resize because the symbols weren't the same size. I'd like the button to look nice. My only option right now is to add a play/pause button that doesn't change.

Comment: @HarishSharma, answers go down there. You'll need to include more than just a link, though.

Comment: Noted and thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can insert an `<img>` tag inside the button like so:

```js
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(audio.paused){
    audio.play();
    buttons.innerHTML = '<img src="https://i.imgur.com/laKFwvv.png" />';
  } else {
    audio.pause();
    buttons.innerHTML = '<img src="https://some/play/icon.png" />';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

in this example i using button tag

```js
var audio, playbtn, mutebtn, seek_bar;
function initAudioPlayer(){
 audio = new Audio();
 audio.src = "https://www.soundjay.com/free-music/midnight-ride-01a.mp3";
 audio.loop = true;
 audio.play();
 // Set object references
 playbtn = document.getElementById("playpausebtn");
 // Add Event Handling
 playbtn.addEventListener("click",playPause);
 // Functions
 function playPause(){
  if(audio.paused){
      audio.play();
      playbtn.style.background = "url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/189/189889.svg) no-repeat";
     } else {
      audio.pause();
      playbtn.style.background = "url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/148/148744.svg) no-repeat";
     }
 }
 
}
window.addEventListener("load", initAudioPlayer);
```

```css
button{ border:none; cursor:pointer; outline:none; }

button#playpausebtn{ background:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/189/189889.svg) no-repeat;
 width:10%;
 height:100px;
  
  display: block;
    margin: auto;
  
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<button id="playpausebtn"></button>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a background image, so you can simply swap that image using `button.style.backgroundImage = 'url(./path/to/image.png)'`, like so:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var audio = document.getElementById("player");

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(audio.paused){
    audio.play();
    button.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://i.imgur.com/laKFwvv.png)';
  } else {
    audio.pause();
    button.style.backgroundImage = 'url(./path/to/image/play.png)';
  }
});
```

```css
#button {
 background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/laKFwvv.png);
 width: 64px;
 height: 64px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 border: 0;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25)
}

#button:active { background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.25); }

body { background: red; }
```

```html
<audio id="player">
  <source src='https://audio.jukehost.co.uk/c926ef6560961d5fd02e35e1488a5997e8217bc1/1a1c12c319a' type='audio/mpeg'/>
</audio>

<button id="button"></button>
```